# PHP Fatal-Error: Call to a member function append_output()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use codeigniter in my blog and since a while I get this error

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function append_output() on a non-object in /var/www/site/blog/system/core/Loader.php on line 862

I don't know what change caused this and why it appears. The site gets rendered and send to browser completely, from views header.php, index.php to footer.php  everything is there and after that this error appears. Search with google showed another site, that has this error at the very bottom of their site...

I now supressed the error with error_reporting(0) as the whole site works fine, but that's not a solution I want to stay with.

It happens on all pages, I have one Controler (blog.php) and several methods like index(), article(), archive() in it. The methods do what they are supposed to do, but when CI finished rendering the page, the error appears, with all controler methods.

What can I do to trace where this problem appears?

Comment: Whatever object you're trying to call `append_output` on, on line 862 in `Loader.php` isn't actually an object. Figure out what object that is - figure out where it's supposed to come from and why it isn't an object. (it looks like the CI instance (which is what I guess comes from `get_instance()` without knowing CI) has no `->output` class.)

Comment: Thats how much I understood of the problem. Loader.php is part of CI core. CI creates a superobject and all user objects extend from there. I never touched Loader.php or any other of the core files, I coded everything in my own controller, model, views.

Comment: Did you overwrite the `output` class? Perhaps with something that isn't an object? ([Perhaps you've replaced `$this->output` with a string or something?](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/output.html)). The easiest way to check it is to add `var_dump($_ci_CI->output)` right above the line and figure out what it contains.

Comment: Nope I didnt use $this->output anywhere. Also what puzzles me is, that the site gets rendered completely but after $this->load->view('index', $this->data) the fatal error appears. However $this->load->view is the last call in the index method. If I add an echo after that line, it doesn't get there, echo 'test' before load->view     is processed.

Comment: If I was you I'd add a bunch of `var_dump($this->output)`'s to your controller before you do anything, after you do some stuff, and before the page renders just to check where it suddenly gets replaced.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php#L938
If the error is occurring on the value returned from `get_instance`, here will be your problem.  Although you may have to look at the version you are using to get the right line number.

Additionally:
https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Controller.php#L75

This appears to be the singleton class that function leads to, it is returning `self::$instance` which is created in the constructor.

To me this means the CI_Controller singleton has not been instantiated at the time that error has occurred.

Hope that helps you debug your problem.

Comment: Well what I wonder is, why it still renders the site and then throws an fatal error after everything is processed (all views loaded)...

Comment: @JherekCarnelian If you look at the comments on the source code referenced you can see that it's trying to flush all nested output buffers (in case your view renders another view). This is what fails. The reason it looks the same is probably because you don't *have* any nested output buffers/views.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I'd overwritten the output class ($this->output) in my controller.